# French equivalent of the English expression "cat lady"?

Tags: anglais, expressions

What is the French equivalent of the English expression "cat lady," i.e., the stereotypical woman who has lots of cats and is overly invested in them, to the detriment of human relationships? I'm not talking about animal hoarders, just regular cat ladies. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Il y a en effet souvent, (peut-être dans chaque quartier ?) une dame esseulée, parfois agée mais pas toujours, qu'on finit par désigner comme **« la dame aux chats »** (quelques résultats assez pertinents pour une recherche sur l'expression entière entre guillemets).

En revanche, il me semble que c'est difficile à transformer pour en faire un nom commun, et parler de *dames aux chats* dans un sens générique serait probablement étrange hors contexte spécifique.

Comment: Peut-on savoir exactement ce que c'est que ce « 110 000 résultats » ? J'ai peur que ce soit une absurdité affichée par Google.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Effectivement, le nombre de résultats affiché par Google est très fantaisiste, surtout lorsqu'il y a plusieurs mots. *La dame aux chats* est une proposition de traduction valable, mais ça n'a pas la même connotation qu'en anglais, ça peut très bien être une dame qui se trouve avoir des chats (et qui peut très bien avoir aussi un mari, des enfants, ...).

Comment: @Stephane Je t'invite à faire la recherche en question, il m'a semblé que les résultats étaient au contraire très pertinents, et qu'ils attestent de la popularité de l'expression. De quelle absurdité parles-tu ?

Comment: @Gilles J'insiste sur la nécessité de grouper les termes de la recherche avec des guillemets, sinon les résultats sont effectivement fantaisistes.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Le **nombre** de résultats donné par Google est fantaisiste, avec ou sans guillemets. Par exemple à l'instant http://www.google.com/search?q=%22la+dame+aux+chats%22 me donne `about 61,700 results` sur les trois premières pages et `about 153,000` sur la quatrième.

Comment: @Gilles au temps pour moi, je pensais à la *pertinence* des résultats... en effet, le nombre, lui, est étrangement inconsistant, je ne l'avais pas remarqué. Quoi qu'il en soit, l'appellation est vraisemblablement plus populaire que les autres propositions avancées (*femme chat*, *femme à chats*, *dame chat*, *mémère à chat*).

Comment: Voici ce qu'il affiche sur la **dernière** page : « Page 40 of about 390 results (0.29 seconds) »…

Comment: @Stephane Quelle autre expression trouves-tu plus pertinente ?

Comment: Je n'en ai trouvé aucune, je ne faisais que commenter ce nombre totalement erroné renvoyé par Google.  La phrase entre parenthèses par quelque chose de concret et de vrai « **Google** a trouvé **390** résultats », et mes commentaires n'ont plus lieu d'être.

Comment: Quoi qu'il en soit, vos remarques sont justes : j'ai édité ma réponse en ce sens.

Answer (score 4):

J'ai entendu, parfois de façon péjorative, le remplacement de *femme* par *mémère* pris ici dans le sens de mère plus ou moins frustrée qui inclut le chat dans sa propre descendance.

> C'est une mémère à chat qui reporte toute son affection sur une douzaine de félidés.

Cette expression est plutôt familière et sera délicate d'emploi dans d'autres circonstances.

Comment: Follow up question: Would a literal translation of "cat lady" be "une dame chat"?

Comment: @Erika Yes, in the sense of a cat who is a female with an upper-class connotation. But it isn't idiomatic. In the sense of a lady who is into cats, *femme à chats* is a literal translation, but it sounds weird and doesn't evoke anything in particular.

Comment: @Erika - *equivalent* et *literal* ne sont littéralement pas équivalents.

Comment: @cl-r: well said, and point taken!

Comment: Dans le même genre il y a  "punk à chien".

Answer (score 3):

Pour décrire cette situation les expressions que j'ai le plus communément entendues sont « **vieille à chats** » ou « **vieille aux chats** ». Le problème étant que ces expressions ne s'appliquent qu'à des femmes âgées et sont plus insultantes que la version anglaise.

--

What I've heard the most to describe the "cat lady" situation is "**vieille à chats**" or "**vieille aux chats**", but both only apply to elderly women and are more offensive than the english version.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such expression in French. You can say "une femme à chats" but this expression is rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

Alhough the stereotype of a middle-aged to elderly woman who dotes too much on a pet is not unknown outside the anglosphere, I am not aware of a simple French term encapsulating the entire stereotype.

Answer (score 1):

Comme indiqué par S73ph4n, il n'existe pas d'expression consacrée ayant le même sens que "cat lady".

Le plus proche serait l'appellation de "vieille fille". Ce n'est pas une expression très utilisée mais ça a la même connotation. Cela désigne une femme d'âge moyen ou élevé qui n'a jamais été mariée ou eu des enfants, et qui vit seule. Malheureusement il manque les chats, même si on a tendance à faire le lien assez inconsciemment...

Answer (score 0):

Although rather insensitive (read: ‘offensive’), I’ve often seen and heard (and, yes, sometimes used myself) *crazy* added to “cat lady” to gratuitously and judgmentally emphasize the potential gravity of the situation and affliction.

Perhaps the best known [“**Crazy Cat Lady**” is Eleanor Abernathy](https://www.facebook.com/pg/Crazy-cat-lady-folle-aux-chats-37628977092/photos/?tab=album&album_id=37629252092), a fairly frequent character on “The Simpsons” TV show, and the previous link leads to “her” Facebook page where “**Folle aux chats**” is seemingly used to translate “Crazy Cat Lady.”

“Folle aux chats” is also used in the book [*S'épanouir: Réussir sans défaillir*](https://books.google.com/books?id=e3alCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT61&dq=%22folle+aux+chats%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR_oKXvL_RAhXKSiYKHb_UDoAQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22folle%20aux%20chats%22&f=false) (by Arianna Huffington, via *GoogleBooks*) for the French version of a cliched term ("cat lady," I presume) used to (inaccurately, according to Ms Huffington) describe socially isolated people who enjoy affection from and, in turn, give their affection to animals instead of humans.

For what little it's worth, *Reverao-Context* also provides a few examples where [“folle aux chats”](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/folle+aux+chats) is translated by “crazy/freaking cat lady”, and even has one or two without the “crazy” modifier:

> On dirait la folle aux chats. == You kind of look like a crazy cat
>   lady.
>
> Ton look "folle aux chats" attirera l'attention. == Your "cat lady"
>   look is not gonna fit in in there.

Finally, in an, imo, entertaining *You-Tube* video published by Nyska34 in April of 2016 (please note, however, that profanity is used), Ms Nyska seems to use [“LA FOLLE AUX CHATS”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbaKQ80kR3Q) to translate the video game “Spinster Cat Lady” (where the “spinster” in the English title corresponds with the notion of "vieille fille," as given in a recent answer by @Cartolin).  Please note, however that, as far as I can tell, this translation only appears in the written title of the video, for I don't think Ms Nyska34 ever actually uses it in the video itself.

(please note, also, that “folle **des** chats” is found and can, imo, also be used in this sense, but my impression is that it’s used more as an adjective phrase [e.g., “Elle est folle des chats”] than as a noun phrase [Elle est **La** folle des chats”] and that, as a noun phrase, “La/une folle **aux** chats” is better than “La/une folle **des** chats" to capture the English noun phrase at issue (i.e., **The/a** [crazy/spinster] cat lady), whereas “la" [and especially] "**une** folle **des** chats” is better suited to describe someone who is “simply” crazy about cats, but who isn’t quite [yet?] a certifiable “[crazy] cat lady”)